# AWS EC2 instance is running but I am not able to connect

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I got my angular app in EC2 instance running successfully[image]

But I am unable to hit the url, as the address is not found. The application runs in 4200 default port, so I tried connecting instance name:4200. I am new to the AWS and I came till this and got stuck. pls advice.

Comment: Do you see any error in the browser console when you try to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/`?

Comment: Did you configure your security group? e.g. https://imgur.com/a/7AAiyoJ

Comment: Ensure port 4200 is not being blocked by the OS firewall (e.g., iptables). Also ensure you opened port 4200 in the ec2 security group in which your instance is running.

Comment: ng serve binds to localhost:4200, use ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 and also perform the above to allow traffic to reach the instance.

Comment: Faced a similar issue, for me it was my VPN that was restricting me to connect.
try to curl http://localhost:4200/ if that works then must be something wrong with accessing the URL from you local machine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to try enter to the instance a curl to the localhost:4200 If you have a successful connection, the troubleshooting line will be the following

- View the Firewall configuration, check if you have allowed the inbound traffic to the instances
- View the aws security groups configurations, see if you have allowed the inbound connection to the port 4200
- The last thing view the network configuration are you sure this instance has a public IP associated? Is your VPC configured with an Internet gateway?

I hope this steps help you, If you need more detail help next time put more context about your issue